# Google Maps asking for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, google-maps-sdk-ios, user-permissions

I have an iOS app that uses the Google maps library which I have added via CocoaPods. This app fetches user location even in background so it asks the user for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

But upon running the app from Xcode, I get the correct permission alert but I also get the following error message in the console.

> This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a
>   usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining
>   to the user how the app uses this data

Doesn't `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` automatically allow when in usage as well? Because I don't want the When In Use option to be available in the Settings because if the user later changes to that, it will cause the app to behave not as intended.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a key value pair of NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription as key and value is like you have to notify user , or something else that user can understand that this app is going to use gps location.

You can try this or add this in your plist

Privacy - Location Always Usage Description as key and

Application would like to use your location. By allowing background locations, we can notify you when a customer is requesting for service. Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life as value

Comment: I understand how to use it but that's not the issue I'm facing though.

Comment: That is because , if people will use your app the they should know about how you will use their location and what you are doing with that . Apple has now decide to give this for this reason only.